# Testng to print result pass/ fail

Tags: java, testng, junit4

Here, I am trying to print the results of testcases...
But whatever I do the test reult prints only as 16...
I want it to print as success or pass/ fail
It would be a great help if you could post a example.

```
public class EdiitAttendancePunchesByDepartment {

    public EdiitAttendancePunchesByDepartment() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
    }
    Boolean t = true;

    @Test(priority = 0,dataProvider = "globalcfg")
    public void global(String propid, String propvalue) throws IOException {
        ConfigurationBean cfgbean = new ConfigurationBean();

        for (ConfigurationModel cc : cfgbean.getConfigurationList()) {
            if (cc.getPropertyId().equals(propid)) {
                cc.setPropertyId(propid);
                cc.setPropertyValue(propvalue);
                System.out.println("Propid : " + cc.getPropertyId() + " value : " + cc.getPropertyValue());
            }
        }

        File output = new File("D:/data/kishore/Edit_punches_output.xls");
        FileWriter writes = new FileWriter(output.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writes);
        bw.write("EmpID-Date-Punch_Times-PayDay-Total_IN_Hours-OT-TEST_ID-Leave_Type");
        bw.close();

        cfgbean.setCreateButtonFlag(Boolean.FALSE);
        cfgbean.setUpdateButtonFlag(Boolean.TRUE);
        cfgbean.updateConfiguration();
        cfgbean.retrieveConfiguration();
        for (ConfigurationModel cc : cfgbean.getConfigurationList()) {
            if (cc.getPropertyId().equals(propid)) {
                System.out.println("Propid Out Put : " + cc.getPropertyId() + " value Out Put: " + cc.getPropertyValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Global Config running>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
         boolean tr=Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().isSuccess();
         System.out.println("Check<><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>"+tr);
         if(tr==true){
             System.out.println("Result /////////////////////////////////////"+tr);
         }
        System.out.println("Test result>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getStatus());
    }

    @Test(priority = 1,dataProvider = "viewpunches")
    public void testviewpunches(String cmpcode, String orgcode, String Empid, String Empname, String deptname, Integer compgrpid,
            String date, String Time1, String Time2, String type, String typeid) {

        EditEmpTimeSheetBean bean = new EditEmpTimeSheetBean();
        bean.setCmpCode(cmpcode);
        bean.setOrgCode(orgcode);
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date date1 = format.parse(date);
            Date time1 = format1.parse(Time1);
            Date time3 = format1.parse(Time2);
            SimpleDateFormat op = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

            bean.setTimeSheetDate(date1);
            bean.setEmpCompGroupId(compgrpid);
            bean.setDepartmentName(deptname);

            bean.setEmployeeCode(Empid);
            bean.setEmployeeName(Empname);
            bean.setDialogFlag(Boolean.TRUE);
            bean.viewTimeSheetDetailByDepartment();

            EmployeeDTO dto = new EmployeeDTO();
            EmployeeService service = new EmployeeServiceImpl();
            dto = service.retrieveEmployee(bean.getCmpCode(), bean.getOrgCode(), bean.getEmployeeCode());
            if (dto == null) {
                File output = new File("D:/data/kishore/Edit_punches_output.xls");
                FileWriter write_new = new FileWriter(output, true);
                BufferedWriter bw_new = new BufferedWriter(write_new);
                bw_new.write("\n" + bean.getEmployeeCode() + "- NO record found - - - - -" + typeid);
                bw_new.close();
                System.out.println("Invalid Employee Code");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Valid code");
            }


            for (EmpWorkLogModel cc : bean.getEmpWorkLogArray()) {
                if (cc.getEmployeeCode().equals(Empid)) {
                    cc.onChange();
                    List<LogTimeModel> kl = new ArrayList<LogTimeModel>();
                    LogTimeModel m = new LogTimeModel();
                    LogTimeModel mn = new LogTimeModel();

                    m.setPunchTimes(time1);
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")) {
                        m.setOpFlag(Constant.OP_FLAG_INSERT);
                    }
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
                        m.setOpFlag(Constant.OP_FLAG_UPDATE);
                    }
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                        m.setOpFlag(Constant.OP_FLAG_DELETE);
                    }
                    mn.setPunchTimes(time3);
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")) {
                        mn.setOpFlag(Constant.OP_FLAG_INSERT);
                    }
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
                        mn.setOpFlag(Constant.OP_FLAG_UPDATE);
                    }
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
                        mn.setOpFlag(Constant.OP_FLAG_DELETE);
                    }
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("CHANGE")) {
                    }
                    kl.add(m);
                    kl.add(mn);
                    cc.setPunchList(kl);
                    System.out.println("punch time>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>XXXXXXXXX>>>>>>>>>>>>XXXXXXXXXX   " + mn.getPunchTimes() + "       " + cc.getPunchTime() + "   " + cc.getFromDate());

                    System.out.println("Emp ID : " + cc.getEmployeeCode() + " \nPunch time : " + cc.getPunchTimes() + " \nPay Day : " + cc.getPayDay() + " \nIN hours: " + cc.getWorkedTime());

                } else {

                    System.out.println("\n\nNo Records found for : " + cc.getEmployeeCode());
                }
            }System.out.println("Test result>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getStatus());
            bean.updateLogTime();
            testview(bean.getEmployeeCode(), bean.getEmployeeName(), bean.getShiftId(), date, typeid);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" Error :" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This is the output i receive

> sessionFactory1 org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@196a6ac
>   sessionFactory1 SessionStatistics[entity count=0collection count=0]
>   Propid : com.rgs.payroll.enableDynamicWeekOff value : N Propid Out Put
>   : com.rgs.payroll.enableDynamicWeekOff value Out Put: N Global Config
>   running> Check<><><><><><><><><><>false Test result>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 16

Comment: The problem would appear to be in this piece of code `Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getStatus()`. I don't see the source code for this listed, but I would suggest looking at what `getStatus()` is returning

Comment: you can implement either listener (ITestListener) or IReporter to print the results the way you want

Answer (score 1):

Remove pass fail decision making code from ur test case and use the below code:

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) {

   if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
   System.out.println(result.getMethod().getMethodName()+ " is failed");
   //do something here.
   }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`16` means ["STARTED"](http://testng.org/javadocs/constant-values.html#org.testng.ITestResult.STARTED).

It's the only value you can expect into the test itself.
TestNG will only determine the value after the end of the method.

You can try to print the result from the `@AfterMethod` method.